# Emacs org-mode: how to apply a change in configuration file to agenda?

Tags: emacs, org-mode, elisp

I'm using `GNU Emacs 24.1.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601)` with `org-mode 7.9.3d` on `Windows 7`.

I'm currently testing new agenda settings and I have my agenda settings like `(setq org-agenda-custom-commands ...` in a separate file which is loaded in my emacs by something like

`load "C:\path\mysettings.el"` in my .emacs file.

So my **question** is:
**If I made a change to this open mysettings.el buffer, what do I have to do to apply it to my open agenda?**

- I assume I have to save the buffer mysettings.el
- and rebuild the agenda buffer by pressing "g".
- Do I have to do M-x eval-buffer or something else before successfully rebuilding the agenda?

It seems to me that this alone is not sufficient to make the changes work?! What else do I have to do?

*Sorry, if this might be a stupid/trivial question for experienced users*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the cursor at the end of the expression `(setq org-agenda-custom-commands ...)|` and call `M-x eval-last-expression RET`. You can see the current value of the variable `org-agenda-custom-commands` by `M-x eval-expression RET (describe-variable 'org-agenda-custom-commands) RET`.